# Ruby + ActiveRecord: How to configure a date field resulting in 'yyyy-mm-dd' date format?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord 4.2.4 to work with database.

Some background:

- Ruby '1.9.3'
- ActiveRecord '4.2.4'
- Cucumber '2.1.0'
- I am not using Rails.

I recently ran into this issue, the output file that was generated shows:

```
   ROLE             | UPDATED_DATE
   Teacher          | 2016-10-26 09:54:06 UTC
```

But what do not want '2016-10-26 **09:54:06 UTC**' in the UPDATED_DATE, I expect only '2016-10-26' to show in the file, like below:

```
   ROLE             | UPDATED_DATE
   Teacher          | 2016-10-26
```

The UPDATED_DATE column has a type of DATE in the table. I execute the query without converting it to anything. And I am not using Ruby object/model to map the database table, instead I only simply run the SQL and print out the results into a file. Here is what I have in the code:

```
 def initialize
   ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes = false

   db_config = DBConfig.get_config_file(DB_CONFIG)
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter =>  db_config['adapter'],
    :username => db_config['username'],
    :password => db_config['password'],
    :database => db_config['database']
  )

  @connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end

def extract_file
  delimiter = '|'
  output_file = 'extract.txt'
  query = "Select role, UPDATED_DATE from ROLE where USER_ID = 'user1'"
  # loop through the result
  File.open(output_file, 'w'){|f|
    result = @connection.exec_query(query)
    result.rows.each do |row|
      array << (row.join(delimiter))
      if array.length >= 100
        f.puts array.join("\n")
        array = []
      end
    end
end
```

I tried to add the line below:

```
   ActiveRecord::Timestamp.record_timestamps = false
```

However, I got the following error:

```
  undefined method `record_timestamps=' for ActiveRecord::Timestamp:Module
```

According to the site:

```
     http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/4.2.4/ActiveRecord/Timestamp

     Timestamping can be turned off by setting:

     config.active_record.record_timestamps = false
```

Where to configure it? In the config/database.yml file? Please share your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When you are only interested in the date of the last update and not the time, then there are two option:

1. Don't use a `updated_at` `timestamp` column in your database. Instead use a `updated_on` `date` column and Rails magic will do the rest. Or
2. cast your `timestamp` to the `date` data type before writing into the output file. A simple `updated_at.to_date` will do the job.